# Automapper - mapping an overriden property leads to casting Exception

Tags: c#, automapper

We just upgraded from Automapper 3.3.0 to 6.0.2 and after upgrading our solution, one of the mappings does not seem to work anymore.

Consider this :

```
public class Source{
   public Decimal GrossAmount {get;set;}
}

public class DerivedSource : Source{
}

public class DestinationMaster{
   public virtual DestinationChild Child {get;set;}
}

public class DestinationChild{
   public decimal GrossAmount {get;set;}
}

public class DerivedDestinationMaster : DestinationMaster {
   private DerivedDestinationChild _destinationChild;

   public override DestinationChild Child {
      get{return _destinationChild;}
      set{_destinationChild = (DerivedDestinationChild)value;}
   }
}

public class DerivedDestinationChild : DestinationChild{
  public string OtherProperty {get;set;}
}
```

And now for the mappings :

```
CreateMap<Source,DestinationMaster>()
  .Include<DerivedSource,DerivedDestinationMaster>();

CreateMap<DerivedSource,DerivedDestinationMaster>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Child, act=> act.MapFrom(src => new DerivedDestinationChild(){ GrossAmount = src.GrossAmount }));
```

Now, if I try to map a "Source" object to a new"DerivedDestinationMaster" instance, I get an Exception telling that I cannot convert "DestinationChild" to "DerivedDestinationChild".

If I put a breakpoint in the "setter" accessor in the overriden property, I clearly see that the passed instance is of type "DestinationChild".  I can also see that there is two constructor calls for the "DestinactionChild" class.  The "GrossAmount" value is the good one from the "Source" object and not 0, as if, after creating and instance of "DerivedDestinationChild", it creates a new instance of "DestinationChild" to receive the information and automaps the two objects.

Our scenario is a bit more complex (we use a IValueResolver), but we tested with the "MapFrom", "UseValue" and a custom Resolver and in all cases, the final instance is not of the derived type.

If we put a "act.Ignore()" on the mapping, the Exception is not raised

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

As document [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance), the mapping follows a certain order for inheritance trees.  The way you can get it working is by duplicating some maps, is that a viable solution for you?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Source, DestinationMaster>().ForMember(dest => dest.Child, act => act.MapFrom(s => new DestinationChild { GrossAmount = s.GrossAmount}));
            cfg.CreateMap<DerivedSource, DerivedDestinationMaster>().IncludeBase<Source, DestinationMaster>().ForMember(dest => dest.Child, act => act.MapFrom(s => new DerivedDestinationChild { GrossAmount = s.GrossAmount }));
        });

        var source = new Source() {GrossAmount = 99};
        var destinationMaster = Mapper.Map<DestinationMaster>(source);
        Debug.Assert(destinationMaster.Child.GrossAmount == source.GrossAmount);
        Debug.Assert(destinationMaster.Child.GetType() == typeof(DestinationChild));

        var derivedSource = new DerivedSource() {GrossAmount = 10};
        var derivedDestinationMaster = Mapper.Map<DerivedDestinationMaster>(derivedSource);
        Debug.Assert(derivedDestinationMaster.Child.GrossAmount == derivedSource.GrossAmount);
        Debug.Assert(derivedDestinationMaster.Child.GetType() == typeof(DerivedDestinationChild));
    }
}
```

Other than that I am not sure how you could return a specific derived type with the `GrossAmount` mapped from the base mapping.